# Understanding weighted standard deviation

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

Here is the formula that I use for weighted standard deviation: http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman2/ch2/weightsd.pdf.

My question is: why do we care about the number of nonzero weights? Isn't the value of 
N'-1 / N' very close to one?

Also, if I am also calculating the weighted absolute standard deviation (like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_deviation#Mean_absolute_deviation_.28MAD.29, but weighted), do I need to care about the number of nonzero weights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of nonzero weights is effectively the sample size. If we have $w_i=0$ then we are ignoring the $i$th observation, so it doesn't really count as part of our sample.

You are also correct that $(N'-1)/N'$ will be close to one if $N$ is large. The reason that this isn't just ignored in the first paper you cited is because we like our estimators to be *unbiased*. That is, we want $E[s]=\sigma$, and we want $E[s_w] = \sigma$ where $\sigma$ is the true population standard deviation, and $E$ denotes the expected value.

It just so happens that by using this strange looking formula, it actually turns out that $s,s_w$ are unbiased estimators of $\sigma$. This is a tedious exercise to show, but it is accessible to an undergraduate level statistics student.

As for your second comment, if you are calculating weighted absolute standard deviation as in the first paper you linked, then yes of course, $N'$ appears directly in the formula. As for modifying the MAD formula on wikipedia to be weighted somehow, I would imagine it would appear in much the same way, though it is not immediately obvious to me how to modify that formula in an unbiased manner.

Comment: Thank you. [This](http://omanto.com/averageDeviation.png) is the formula I am using for absolute deviation. I can see now how I would correct the bias. However, I am not calculating the SD for the purpose of probability. I am finding the SD for the purpose of measuring force dispersion. Do I still need to correct the bias?

Comment: Well you don't *need* to use an unbiased estimator, but it is something that you should want to have, otherwise your estimator might not be estimating what you think it is. As long as you can live the amount of error you make, it is okay. Also I should mention that the (wieghted) mean absolute deviation is **not** the same as the standard deviation, and will not necessarily converge to $\sigma$ by making the sample size large. MAD and SD are two totally different quantities, though they have some spiritual similarities in "measuring variability about the mean".

Comment: Regarding MAD, is it possible/necessary to correct the bias? And how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Actually your $D$ actually is an unbiased estimator for the MAD, assuming $y_m$ stands for the unweighted sample mean. Indeed, $$E[D] = E\frac{\sum w_i |y_i-y_m|}{\sum w_i} = \frac{\sum w_i E|y_i-y_m|}{\sum w_i} = E|y_1-y_m| = \frac 1n \sum E|y_i-y_m| = \mathrm{MAD}.$$ Here we used the fact that $E|y_i-y_m|$ is independent of $i$, and to make this claim we need $y_m = \frac 1n \sum y_i$ to be symmetric with respect to relabelings of the $y_i$.